# Stopped release upgrade in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, do-release-upgrade

I was upgrading to ubuntu 20.04 from 18.04, after fetching some details, It said that needs to get around ~4Gb of archives. It asked to press `y/n` to continue upgrade. I pressed `N` but now when I run `apt-get update` command ,it fetches details from focal(20.04) upgrade.

Have I messed something up?

Comment: Change your /etc/apt/sources.list entries from `focal` back to `bionic`. Likely no harm done beyond that.

Comment: I did that, but after restarting, my keyboard and mouse are not working.